# What does the '0x0'. do in this equation $intTotal += '0x0'.$value;

Tags: php, int

Sorry I am new to php and am getting very confused on a bit of code I am working on.

So I get that  `intTotal += $value;` would just add the value to the `intTotal` but how does the `$intTotal += '0x0'.$value;` works? I am getting all sorts of random differences when I chance the `0x0` to something else as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$intTotal += '0x0'.$value;` converts `$value` from *hexadecimal number in string* to format usable by php and then adds it to `$intTotal` (after typecasting from string to int).

Edited to add clarity.

Comment: To what end would someone convert $value to hex just to add it to the $intTotal. Would it not just be adding the same number however in hex as apposed to base 10.

Comment: Essentially I am attempting to reverse engineer this code so trying to nut out the logic.

Comment: `$value` is hexadecimal number stored as string, one approach of converting it to int is using `+= '0x0'.$value`. Using just `+= $value` consideres `$value` to be decimal, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`$value` is apparently a string representing a number in hexadecimal.

The string concatenation (the `.` operator) prefixes it with `0x0`, the `0x` prefix is used to denote a hexadecimal number (the extra zero is superfluous).

So for example if `$value = "f"`, this will produce `0x0f`.  This will then be converted to the integer 15 by PHP, and added to `$intTotal`.

Comment: Ah got it, seems a bit hacky but I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

0x0 is just a regular 0 in hexadecimal representation that gets cast to string '0' when used with the variable syntax